# Python- advancing output to new line with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to have the saying "It's all done." advance to the next line. I've tried everything I can think of and find in my book but the line is continued on the line of integers. This is my coding so far and everything works but I can't figure out how to advance the saying to the next line. Thanks for your help!

```
for x in range(100,-1,-10) :
    print(x, end=' ')

print('It\'s all done.')
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
for x in range(100,-1,-10) :                                                    
    print(x, end=' ')    

print('\nIt\'s all done.')
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe it was that simple! I knew it had to do with "\n" but I wasn't placing it in the proper place! Thank you, it worked!

Comment: Yes,  just add a `\n` or add a `print()` before `print('It\'s all done.')`.